# c- Segmentation Fault when trying to add to char array in Struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct, segmentation-fault, structure

This code is me trying to do different functions for seating arrangement:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NAME_LENGTH 200
#define NUMBER_OF_SEATS 12
```

struct in question:

```
//Create the struct (visible to all functions)
struct seat{
int id;
int marker; //0 for available, 1 for occupied
char customerName[NAME_LENGTH];
};
//Declare the array of struct (visible to all functions)
struct seat seats[NUMBER_OF_SEATS];
```

This is the menu for navigating the program

```
void showNumberOfSeatsAvailable();
void assignASeat();
void deleteSeatAssignment();
void printSeats();
int main(void) {
setbuf(stdout, NULL);

int choice = 1;
int isQuit = 0;
//Initialize seats' ID
for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_SEATS; i ++){
    seats[i].id = i + 1;
}

printSeats();

//User interaction
do{
    //Step 1: Display the memu
    puts("To choose a function, enter its number label:");
    puts("1). Show number of seats available;");
    puts("2). Assign a customer to a seat;");
    puts("3). Delete a seat assignment;");
    puts("4). Quit");

    //Step 2: accept user input: the choice
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    //Step 3: Execute corresponding performance based on user choice
    switch(choice){
    case 1:
        showNumberOfSeatsAvailable();
        break;
    case 2:
        assignASeat();
        break;
    case 3:
        deleteSeatAssignment();
        break;
    case 4:
        isQuit = 1;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    if(isQuit == 1)
        break;
}while(1 == 1);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void printSeats(){
}
```

Where I think the problem is coming from

```
void assignASeat(){
char name[200];
puts("Implement the functionality of assigning a custumer to a seat");
//step 1: check if there is any seat available
 int available;

for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_SEATS; i ++){

    if(seats[i].marker ==0 ){
        available++;
    }
}
if (available >= 1){ 
    printf("you're in luck! Theres Seats!\n");
for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_SEATS; i ++){
    if(seats[i].marker ==0){
        seats[i].marker = 1;
        printf("Enter Customer name: ");
        scanf(" %c",  seats[i].customerName[200]);
        printf("        \n");
        seats[i].customerName[200] = name;
        printf( " %c has been assigned a seat\n",name);
        break;
    }
    }
}
else {
    printf("All seats are booked");
}

}
void showNumberOfSeatsAvailable(){
}
void deleteSeatAssignment(){
}
```

The problem comes when I try to set the name of the Customer name. The following is my output after naviagting the menu and choose Assign a Seat:

```
Implement the functionality of assigning a custumer to a seat                                                                       
you're in luck! Theres Seats!                                                                                                       
Enter Customer name: John doe                                                                                                          
Segmentation fault
```

Any idea why I'm getting this? Ive been looking around but can seem to find a solution. Any help would be nice. Thanks

Comment: seats[i].customerName[200] = name ....

Comment: `available` is uninitialized

Comment: You cannot assign a string to another string. Use `strcpy` to copy from one string to another string.

Comment: <O/T> Since you don't really care how many seats are available, just whether or not a seat is available, recommend breaking out of your `for` loop once you find the first empty seat. Furthermore, you could `#include <stdbool.h>` and change that to `bool available`

Comment: `scanf(" %c",  seats[i].customerName[200]);` The function `scanf` expects an address as parameter to store the string. You provide a `char`. Treating the value of a character as an address is very likely not a good idea. Also index 200 is out of bounds. Also for strings you need format specifier `"%s"`. You have loads of undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can not assign `seats[i].customerName[200] = name` in C.For copying string values in c you should use `strcpy()` standard library function.

```
  char name[200];
  printf("Enter the name:\n");
  scanf("%s",name);
  strcpy(seats[i].customerName,name);
  .
  .
```